# Display text in excel cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

Trying to display the text of one cell (from sheet 1) into another cell (sheet 2) which also has a count (already have fx for the count) and conditional formatting.

Example sheet here [Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EqloFNTarZGUqm48wessgIaD4PaLwm5IuWeTiljtqcw/edit?usp=sharing)

I am trying to set something up like this
[Hell needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AG9B.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `&`to concatenate 2 results, eg:
`=sum(4,4)&" "&A2`
[image]

Comment: But won't that make it a manual process (having to select) the cell?  I am trying to automate.  Essentially the cell will check the counts and (what I want) then display the rounder name

Comment: Using concatenate did work but it shows the count & rounder&both rouder names.  
This is the fx `=COUNTIFs('Raw Data'!B:B, "Test Dep", 'Raw Data'!C:C, "Week 1", 'Raw Data'!D:D, "Yes")&CONCATENATE('Raw Data'!A:A)`
This is what displayed "1RounderMeYou"

Comment: Is there a way to change the code to only display the rounder name if it meets the fx criteria?